# CorsFilter with Stormpath

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, cors, stormpath

I am trying to build my first application using Stormpath and Spring Boot.  I don't find how to add a CORS Filter to the Stormpath servlet. As a result, my front end app cannot get the authentication token because the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing.

With logs, I am sure that my CORS filter is called on methods that I control but, not on the request /oauth/token.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCorsFilter.class);

    public SimpleCorsFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        log.debug("*********Enter Cors Filter***********");
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        log.debug("******* Exit Cors Filter ****");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

I also tried the approach in this blog https://shuaib.me/stormpath-java-backend/ and added the following lines in application.properties.

```
stormpath.web.accessToken.origin.authorizer.originUris = http://localhost:3002
stormpath.web.filters.cors = something.SimpleCorsFilter
stormpath.web.uris./logout = cors
stormpath.web.uris./register = cors
stormpath.web.uris./oauth/token = cors
```

I also tried to add a FilterRegistrationBean

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

All those attempts have the same results, they work for the methods in my Controllers but not, for the /oauth/token request.

Finally, this my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>stormpath-basic</groupId>
<artifactId>stormpath-basic</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <stormpath.version>1.1.1</stormpath.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stormpath.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${stormpath.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you think you need a CORS filter to get an authentication token? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve and what is the issue you are seeing? BTW, we are currently working on adding the CORs filter to our stack. You can see here the existing code in case you want to copy what is being done there: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/pull/1001

Comment: My front end in Angular doesn't run in the same url as my microservice.  I run stormpath in my service.  When my front end request a token to [myserviceurl]/oauth/token, the token is rejected because it misses the CORS headers.

Comment: You only need to add the origin to `stormpath.web.oauth2.origin.authorizer.originUris =`. No need for a CORS filter for this. See here: https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/appendix/web-stormpath-properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot supports [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/), but it only works for Spring MVC, not Spring Security. Spring Framework provides a [CorsFilter you can use for filter-based frameworks](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#filter-based-cors-support). It looks like you're already doing this with your `FilterRegistrationBean`.

I encountered this same issue last week while [writing a blog post about it](https://stormpath.com/blog/angularjs-spring-boot-tutorial). After debugging, I figured out this was because the main `StormpathFilter` comes before the `CorsFilter`.

To fix this, add the following to `application.properties`.

```
stormpath.web.stormpathFilter.order=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting in version 1.2.0 the Stormpath Java SDK will provide a CORS filter out of the box. It will be enabled by default with the following options:

```
stormpath.web.cors.enabled = true
#Comma separated list of allowed origins
stormpath.web.cors.allowed.originUris =
stormpath.web.cors.allowed.headers = Content-Type,Accept,X-Requested-With,remember-me
stormpath.web.cors.allowed.methods = POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE
```

These properties will be customizable via your `application.properties` file.